# how i can change mouse cursor on mouseover to "default" but in sortable be "move" using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It doesn't work

```
$("#sortable").mouseover(function(){ 
    $(this).css("cursor","default"); 
});
$("#sortable").sortable({ cursor: "move" });
```

I need in mouse over cursor:default but in sortable cursor:move

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for that. You can use CSS:

```
#sortable li { cursor:move; }
```

Here `sortable` is the element you've made sortable and `li` are the sortable items.

**[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/343/)**

Comment: thx for your help but you don't understand me i need in mouse over the table cursor :default but when user move the element the cursor change to move

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, this is the officially supported way:

$("#sortable").sortable({ cursor: "move" });